# Turning random.choice into a mutable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to make a hangman game. I currently have a line of code saying `word = (random.choice(open("Level1py.txt").readline()))`.

I'm getting the error `'str' object does not support item assignment`.

Here is the rest of my code (sorry for the mess):

```
import random
def checkLetter(letter, word, guess_word):   
    for c in word:
        if c == letter:
            guess_word[word.index(c)] = c
            word[word.index(c)] = '*'
            print(guess_word) 
word = (random.choice(open("Level1py.txt").readline().split()))
guess_word = ['_' for x in word]
print(guess_word)
while '_' in guess_word:
    guess = input('Letter: ')
    print(checkLetter(guess, word, guess_word))
```

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote and accept. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python. An easy workaround is to use lists, which are mutable:

```
st = "hello"
ls = list(st)
ls[3] = 'r'
st = ''.join(ls)
print(st)
```

Outputs

```
helro
```

Edit: here's how you would implement it in your own code

```
import random
def checkLetter(letter, word, guess_word):
    for c in word:
        if c == letter:
            guess_word[word.index(c)] = c
            word_list = list(word)
            word_list[word.index(c)] = "*"
            word = ''.join(word_list)
            print(guess_word)
word = 'test'
guess_word = ['_' for x in word]
print(guess_word)
while '_' in guess_word:
    guess = input('Letter: ')
    print(checkLetter(guess, word, guess_word))
```

Note that there are still other issues that have nothing to do with this, like printing `None` and duplicate printing

Comment: would you know how to implement your solution into my own code?

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: No problem :) ``

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve your problem using a dictionary:

```
word = "my string" #replace this with your random word
guess_word = {i: '_' for i in set(word)} # initially assign _ to all unique letters
guess_word[' '] = ' ' # exclude white space from the game
wrong_attempts = 0

while '_' in guess_word.values():
    guess = input('Letter: ')
    if guess in guess_word.keys():
        guess_word[guess] = guess
    else:
        wrong_attempts += 1
        if wrong_attempts > 11:
            break
    printable = [guess_word[i] for i in word]
    print(' '.join(printable))

if '_' in guess_word.values():
    print('you lost')
else:
    print('congratulation, you won')
```